# I'm not hearing any sound even though its picked up by audioSource?

Tags: unity, audio, sound

I have two sound clips that I am feeding to an audioSource via script, it seems to be working as I can see the audio clips populating the audioSource component. But the problem is that I dont hear anything.

How ever if I remove the script and manually select the audioclip in source then I can hear both clips clearly. Why is this not working when done through script:

Here is my small script, its choosing two sounds based on the `navMeshAgent` status.

```
public class KnightAudio : MonoBehaviour {

    //private Animator anim;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;

    private AudioSource knightAudio;
    public AudioClip crying; //set this in ispector with audiofile
    public AudioClip scream; //set this in ispector with audiofile

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        knightAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        //anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!agent.isStopped)
        {
            knightAudio.clip = scream;
            knightAudio.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            knightAudio.clip = crying;
            knightAudio.Play();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the audio source, as can be seen it is populating the `crying` clip in there as expected when the agent is stopped and it will change this to `scream` when agent starts moving. But in game I cannot hear any of these.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be that since you're having the audio play every frame that it's constantly restarting the clip making it sound as though nothing is being played.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasnt working was that I was playing it in update without any checks and it was trying to play every frame. Thats why I couldnt hear anything.

Here is the fixed code:

```
void Update () {
        if (!agent.isStopped)
        {
            if(knightAudio.clip != scream)
            {
                knightAudio.clip = scream;
                knightAudio.Play();
            }
            else if (knightAudio.clip == scream && !knightAudio.isPlaying)
                knightAudio.Play();

        }
        else
        {
            if (knightAudio.clip != crying)
            {
                knightAudio.clip = crying;
                knightAudio.Play();
            }
            else if (knightAudio.clip == crying && !knightAudio.isPlaying)
                knightAudio.Play();
        }
    }
```